# Nw.js app build size

Tags: build, size, nw.js

I made a *win64* nw.js app build using version *0.29.4* and a *normal* flavor via *nwjs-build* tool. I got a 169mb app from just one single index.html page. Is this size a minimum for nw.js app or is there a way to make a smaller build? All I need is just a chromium wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NW.js is Node and Chromium so yes, it should weigh more than 100mb.